# How do I figure out freezing when theres no crash logs

Tags: swift, xcode

I keep getting reports from users stating that my app is freezing up. However, I'm not seeing any crash logs/reports related to that bug.

How can I figure out why it's freezing as I don't have access to that users device?

I've tried looking through XCodes crash logs, but there are no crashes.

Comment: A freeze and a crash are completely unrelated. You’re not going to have anything from any users other than maybe their step by step instructions to reproduce the freeze.

Comment: No you can get something from your users, a spindump file. A spindump creates a snapshot of what the app was doing before the app started freezing. You can then use it like a crash report and see which part of your code was called. (You may have to symbolicate it.) Here are good instructions you can send your users: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/206435255-Creating-a-Spindump-file-on-macOS

Comment: You may try using this [tool](https://www.bugsee.com/) which provides a feature of reporting the issues with lot of details like, screen capture, console and network log etc.